# Opposite of ConditionalOnMissingBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So I have a standard Spring Boot web application.  And I have a requirement to allow multiple authentication mechanisms.  So I want to be able to have jar files that handle different authentication.  One for a SAML server, CAS,  OAuth, etc...

I want my "base" war file to use standard jdbc  (Which it does now)  but I want to be able to put my, say, CAS-security.jar in the classpath and have spring use it's AuthenticationProvider.   Right now I have this in my Application.java class

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
    .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}
```

And I @Autowire the provider and service, which are defined as @Bean  as normal...

But I want to annotate (I think) those @Bean definitions to say "Don't use this if there is another one avail"

I want the exact opposite of ConditionalOnMissingBean. Now I suppose I could use that annotation,  and list every possible plugin class that I could use,  but that is bad form as I don't want to recompile/redeploy every time I create a new security plugin.

Is there a `UseThisIfNoOtherBeanExists` type annotation?

In fact, what I really want,  is that I have ALL of my security stuff in say, SecurityConfiguration,  annotated with @Configuration,  and have the whole class replaced with something else if available.

Comment: I would recommend to use the bean overriding mechanism spring offers.

Comment: "I want the exact opposite of ConditionalOnMissingBean." ... "Is there a 'UseThisIfNoOtherBeanExists' type annotation?" Yes, it's `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`, i.e. "only load this if there isn't already another bean of this type."

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you're looking for [`ConditionalOnMissingBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html).  A bean annotated with this will only be used if and only if a bean of its type is not already registered in the bean factory.

If you're somehow not satisfied with that, you have options.  You can peruse [the entire `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition` package](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/package-summary.html) to see if there's something there that best fits your use case.  Alternatively, you could also leverage [`@Conditional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html), and hand-craft a condition based on the environment your application is running in.